# In ArcGIS Pro, how do I create a line between two points that follows the curvature of another shapefile?

Tags: mapping, line, arcgis, point, arcmap

I am fairly new to ArcGIS Pro, and I want to create a line that follows the curvature of a river shapefile and lays between two points. Attached below is a screenshot. I tried using the "Points to Line" tool, but that just gave me a straight line between the two points. Instead, I would like the line to follow along the river from the first point to the second point. I am trying to highlight a sub-reach in a river reach study.

[image: Points and river shapefile.]

[image: Result of "Points to Line."]

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple possible ways...

Manually:

1. Start by making a working copy of your river layer, since we'll be
   messing around with it.
2. Split the river polyline at the points you're interested in, using
   the [Split Line At Point](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-point.htm) tool.
3. Then, delete the estuaries and so on that are not part of the direct
   line from A to B.
4. Finally, [merge the remaining line segments back together](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/merge-features-into-one-feature.htm).

If you have a [Network Analyst](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/what-is-network-analyst-.htm) license, then you can build a network using the rivers and then do a point-to-point route finding.